# Toggle CSS hover element with a Javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Is it possible to use Javascript to toggle an element which changes on hover. I would like to build a button which allows the div to change from the two different states: (1) when the div is not hovered and (2) when the div is hovered.

Any suggestions how this could be done?

Thanks!

TC

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly possible to do this with CSS alone:

```
div { background-color:#000; }
div:hover { background-color:#cc0000; }
```

When you hover over the `div` the background color will turn from black to red.

It is my opinion that using javascript for this task is overkill.  You can do some pretty sophisticated things with the `:hover` pseudo selector.  Consider this markup (and CSS):

`<div>I'm just a div <h1>I'm just an h1</h1></div>`

```
div h1 { font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; }
div:hover { border:1px dotted #000; }
div:hover h1 { font-size:32px; font-weight:bold; color:#cc0000; }
```

As you can see, we can use the `:hover` selector in a rule like above to not only style the hovered element, but any children elements as well.  This premise is how a lot of 'fly out' navigation is made with little more than nested `ul`s.

Comment: div:hover isn't 100% cross-browser compatible

Comment: I imagine your statement was supposed to be "div:hover is not 100% cross-browser compatible."  This is true. IE 6 doesn't like `:hover` on anything but `a` tags by default.  If IE 6 support is required, look at http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/.  This script will enable the use of `:hover` on any element (among many other things).

Comment: @truenorth Are there any browsers aside from IE6 that can't handle it?

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16 for `:hover` compatibility.  All other browsers support the technique I illustrated above.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy, in addition to Nathan's link IE6 doesn't support it on a div and IE7 is partial support, as CSS2 wasn't fully supported when it first shipped, unfortunately.

Comment: The partial support is for the `:active` pseudo selector, `:hover` is fully supported (as it says on the link I provided)

Answer (score 2):

You sure can!

You could do something like:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#mydiv").hover(function () 
{
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    // or $(this).toggle();
  }
);
```

**Standard javascript:**

```
function toggle(obj)
{
    var item = document.getElementById(obj);
    if(item.style.visibility == 'visible') { item.style.visibility = 'hidden'; }
    else { item.style.visibility = 'visible'; }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div onmouseover="toggle('mydiv');" onmouseout="toggle('mydiv');" id="mydiv">Hover</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<input type = 'button' value = 'change div' onmouseover = 'javascript:getElementById('DivId').className = newStyleClass' onmouseout = 'javascript:getElementById('DivId').className = newStyleClass' />`

Answer (score -1):

you can try using jQuery it will make it much easier.  $('#divId').css('hover', function(index){ whatever ; });

If you dont prefer that let me know and I can scratch my brain on how to do it in straight js.